# What is doing every part of this React components, how the state and props comes and goes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to understand how the `props` and `state`s comes and goes. I am commenting the pieces of code that I understand, but there are some others that I can't because I didn't get what is happening.

[This is the code](https://jsbin.com/mazubenaxa/1/edit?js,output)

Or here you might see the code as well:

```
      class TodoList extends React.Component {
        // THIS IS THE PARENT COMPONENT

        // WE DECLARE THE TYPE OF PROPS
        static propTypes = {
          todos: React.PropTypes.array
        }
        // INITIAL STATE OF THE COMPONENT
        constructor(props) {
          super(props)
          this.state = { todos: this.props.todos || [] }
        }

        addTodo = (item) => {
          // WE START MODIFYING THE STATE OF THE COMPONENT
          this.setState({todos: this.state.todos.concat([item])});
        }

        render () {
          return (
            <div className="panel panel-default TodoList">
              <h3>TODO List</h3>
              <TodoItems items={this.state.todos}/>
              <TodoInput addTodo={this.addTodo}/>
            </div>
          );    
        }
      };

      class TodoItems extends React.Component {

        static propTypes = {
          items: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
        }

        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
        }

        render () {
        let createItem;

          createItem = (item, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={index} className="list-group-item">{item}</li>
            );
          };
        return (
            <ul className="TodoItems list-group">
              {this.props.items.map(createItem)}
            </ul>
          );
        }
      };

      class TodoInput extends React.Component {

        constructor (props) {
           super(props);
           this.state = {item: ''};
        }

        onChange = (e) => {
          this.setState({item: e.target.value});
        }

        handleSubmit = (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          this.props.addTodo(this.state.item);
          this.setState({item: ''});
        }

        render () {
          return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="TodoInput">
              <div className="input-group">

                <input type="text"
                       className="form-control"
                       placeholder="Search for..."
                       onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.item}/>

                <span className="input-group-btn">
                  <input className="btn btn-default"
                         type="submit" value="Add" />
                </span>

              </div>
            </form>
          );
        }
      };


      React.render(<TodoList todos={['red','blue']}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

How do you explain what is the `onChange` function doing on `TodoItems` component.

Or how do you explain pieces of code like this:

```
<TodoItems items={this.state.todos}/>
<TodoInput addTodo={this.addTodo}/>
```

why is `this.state.todos` setting the `props` there and and why the name `addTodo={}` there with `this.addTodo`?

Comment: Makes sense to start from the beginning https://facebook.github.io/react/

Comment: this is probably a more useful resource. Helped me a lot https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props are delivered to a component by a parent component by adding attributes to JSX (TodoItems > items and TodoItems > addTodo for example). Props can be data (simple types, arrays etc.) but also references to callback methods in the parent component. These callbacks can be used to communicate data from a component to its parent. Within a component you should think op props as unmutable objects. So you should not change the value of a property.

in your example, a list of todo's (data) is being passed from the state of one component to a property of an underlying (TodoItems) component. TodoInput has an 'addTodo' property that can be used to supply a function (callback) to the 'TodoInput' component that should be called when a todo has been entered by the user. When you supply a callback through the properties to a component, you never supply the parameters ('this.addTodo' vs. 'this.addTodo("Do this")') because you only would like the pointer to the callback and not the return value of the function.

In your example, component 'TodoList' is responsible for maintaining the list of todo's. That's why the list is kept in the state of this component. Every change in the state (invoked by using the 'setState' method) results in a re-render of the 'TodoList' component. Because the 'TodoList' component is responsible for the list, the 'TodoInput' component must supply new items to the 'TodoList' component. This is done by use of the 'addTodo' callback that is called from the 'TodoInput' component when the user adds new information.

Please also take a look at the Flux pattern, because in that pattern, not the component itself is responsible for data storage, but a store is. For larger applications this pattern can help you to make a more stable React application.

Comment: Super clear. Thanks :)